# tinyint in mysql is shown as boolean value in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, tinyint

My query to get a `tinyint(1)` field from a table in mysql in as below

```
mysqlcommand.selectquery="select vehicletype from vehicles where id=1"
```

possible values for `vehicletype` is 1 to 7

but the output in the `datatable` row for the field is shown as `boolean`

```
datatable dtresult;
mda.Fill(dtResult);
DataRow dr = dtResult.Rows[0];
//dr["vehicletype "]=false if 0
//dr["vehicletype "]=true if 1
//dr["vehicletype "]=true if 2
//dr["vehicletype "]=true if 3
//dr["vehicletype "]=true if 4 etc...
```

when i see the value of `dr["vehicletype "]` in visual studio it shows as `false` for 0 and `true` for any other value. How can i prevent it from default conversion

Comment: Have you tried `Int vehicletype = Convert.ToInt32(dr["vehicletype"]);`?

Comment: yes it gives 0 for 0 value and 1 for any other values

Comment: I am having the same problem

Answer (score 5):

Refer to:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67381

> You can add to your connection string 
>   "Treat Tiny As Boolean=false;"
>
> and now the tinyint will be interpreted like a type sbyte in C#.